# Function that remove remote user account

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Are there any functions in netapi32.dll or in some other .dll that can remove a *remote* user account from the Administrators group? Is it possible to do with `NetLocalGroupDelMembers` ?  If it is possible, where are parameters of admin's name and password in this function ?

Comment: This remote machine is not on a domain?

Comment: No, a machine belong to a domain.

Comment: Right, so you most likely want to use Active Directory to tinker with user accounts.

Comment: Yes, i will use ADSI methods to achieve this functionality if user account belongs to group located on domain. Although i can't use ADSI methods if user account locates in admins group on a computer that was added to AD. I want to use WINAPI function to remove user. And I need to do this with the help of rights of domain admins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, as per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370281.aspx) you just pass "domainname\username" in the `LOCALGROUP_MEMBERS_INFO_3` structure.

You don't specify the username and password when calling it, you just need to be running as that user.